# What are some design aspects that I can add for a pink meditation website to make it look interesting?

Tags: html, css

I am making a mental health website for a school project and in there, there is a meditation space which is inspired to be pink because of some famous arts that are pink and are made for relaxation.

I call it pink meditation.

here is a picture of what it currently looks like. I think it looks a little plain. Is there any design recommendations that you think will make it more appealing but still pink. and is this the right shade or should I try another.

I will update the page with your styles and upload the photo so we can discuss.
[image]

Comment: SO isn't very keen on us giving recommendations, but I'll risk it - choosing a pink roughly of that hue has some calming benefits but for short periods only - so may be well suited to an online meditation space. I expect you have read up about 'drunk tank pink'. As it is to be a calm space I'd suggest not adding very much - certainly not lots of images. Perhaps make the text a lot bigger and easier to read and possibly (though I'm not sure about this) look into have a background of a linear-gradient based on the pink. For meditation/calmness remember less is better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thick, dark borders have a very masculine feel. I'd start there. The 10+ pixel rounding gives a 2014 era modern vibe, which I don't think you're looking for. I'd try turning that down.

In all sites, black is very harsh, both for reading, and for portraying any kind of emotion, positive or negative. The easiest way to deal with that is to lighten the red and green, but in your case since the whole site is bubblegum pink, I'd say try the green and blue first to see if you can get a less offensive tone. Not a lot, just a hair off each.

If you want a transcendental meditation feel, have the button backgrounds be transparent and slowly animate in a background on hover. If you want an expertise on your subject matter (meditation) type of feel, make them a solid color, and transition to transparent on hover.

I like to use Coolors for helping to find a palatte to work with (https://coolors.co/). Just remember to stick to it. For whatever you choose your main color to be, make sure you have an error, success, light, dark, and splash color to go with it.

Bubblegum pink is a very loud and bold choice. I'd highly recommend against it as the background color, but could see it working well with a white / cream background as a splash color (where it is the underline, the highlights, etc). It goes well with gold, but only if both it and gold are accents.

You can also use some pastels with it, namely a kind of sun damaged blue or yellow, or a 70s green. See here:

https://www.kidsinteriors.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/danielledotsheehan.jpg

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/RDVrjl0VbpkMQdWhGDC8gjDZhVyKASeEPTuSUJfEPq0Y-ct8lD5iY6QJqUOn_BbWcrkV9DZIuSNCwWv8KvPxh8MUszVK8K4wqcKV7mmllrQleLVTT8U3XP_3Q_wOK-KVt4kJAXptLbbXzeh6pLBky-aOUg

https://i.pinimg.com/474x/5a/75/9d/5a759d754164eafe628b119450c08e06.jpg

These work well in interior design, but are very hard to portray in web design. You'll have a tough time bringing out the good in any of them, as they work best in natural sunlight gradient.

I would also recommend making your pink considerably lighter. Backgrounds shouldn't overwhelm a page unless their intent is to give a foreboding feeling. A nice light pink will let you use the bubblegum as an accent still, while keeping the feminine and calming vibe of a meditation site.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding some images as background or header,
make your elements symmetrical,
add some sidenavs or sideelements,
add some `sticky` elements to your website as your navbar,
if you want to add some animations like animated svgs,
centre out your divs with loopplays and add some images to it,
make an footer with your contact and so on.

Comment: hi, thankyou so much for your comment. I just wanted to know what sticky elements are

Comment: Sticky elements stay with you as youre scrolling down your site. The best elements to make "sticky" are navbar cuz you want it to be with you for the whole time and dont have to scroll up every time you want to use navbar ;)

Comment: here you have an easy tutorial to get to know the sticky property:

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp

Comment: you can also add hover properties on your buttons so for example they change color when you hover your cursor on it

Comment: plz close this post if you have no mor questions ;)

Answer (score 0):

- The pink color doesn't suit the black text. You can try this website for color pallets https://colorhunt.co
- You can also customize your buttons to be more elegant, check this website for buttons https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_buttons.asp
- Design your navigation bar better with colors and interactive buttons. Check this website https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp
- The empty spaces at the side of the website seems a little odd. Try increase the width of your main content, or make your main content into columns so it covers more of the page.